# Meta box losing its value when scheduled post is published

Tags: plugins, post-meta

I've created a plugin with a meta box that has a check box and noticed that when a post goes from scheduled (future) to published the meta is no longer checked.

When I schedule the post and check the box, it stays saved. If the post is published and I check the box it stays checked. Going from published to draft keeps the box checked.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_feature_meta');

function add_feature_meta() {
    if(current_user_can('edit_posts')) {
        add_meta_box('feature_meta_id', 'Feature this Article?', 'feature_meta_box', 'post', 'side', 'high');
    }
}

function feature_meta_box() {
    global $post;
    $feature_data = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'feature_meta_id', true);
    ?>

        <label for="featured-meta"><input type="checkbox" id="featured-meta" name="feature_meta_id" <?php if($feature_data == '1') { echo 'checked'; } ?>> Make this featured</label>

    <?php
}

function k2_feature_meta_save_details($post_id) {
    global $post;

    if((defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) || (defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX)) {
        return;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['feature_meta_id'])) {
        $feature_data = 1;
    } else {
        $feature_data = 0;
    }

    update_post_meta($post_id, 'feature_meta_id', $feature_data);

}

add_action('save_post', 'k2_feature_meta_save_details');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tested this, but my guess is that `$_POST` is not set when the post is saved when `wp_cron` changes the status from "Scheduled" to "Published", and so your value gets saved/reset to 0.

Instead of using `save_post` you could hook to the [several transition hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) that fit your needs.

Or you could remove your action for the one or more transitions that seem to be problematic. For example:

```
add_action(
  'pending_to_publish',
  function($post) {
    remove_action('save_post', 'k2_feature_meta_save_details');
  }
);
```

Untested, but I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, I don't know why that didn't click for me. FYI, I changed `pending_to_published` to `future_to_published`